# The role of the VSPLIT in this CAN transceiver

Tags: can

I want to know how the VSPLIT (Pin 11) in the IC [NCV7341](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/ncv7341-d.pdf) works and what its real effects in the citcuit are.

[image]

In the data sheet it says it is used to stabilise the CAN signals, but how? What does "steps" mean?

Does anyone have signal captures that can show me the differences?

[image]

Comment: This is pretty much an identical duplicate: https://electrical.codidact.com/posts/284323 Same question different transceiver brand.

Comment: oh thanks buddy

Comment: There are many application notes about CAN bus which explain why the chios bias the lines with midpoint voltage. Have you read any? If you change the word "steps" with "changes", do you understand the explanation better? Or do you understand common-mode voltage?

Comment: The tl;dr of the link is basically: it provides a common mode voltage (2.5V) for better EMC characteristics. Both CAN lines will idle at this voltage level.